# OR (||) statement in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have different tables which have rows for IDs. but rows in all table have different names like a_id, m_d etc. 
so i am just curious to know if there is any working "OR statement" that i can use in mysql query?

```
<?php  
    include('db.php');
    include('Admin.php');
    $table=$_GET['tbl'];
    $id=      $_GET['id'];

    $query="DELETE FROM `$table` WHERE (m_id=$id  OR id=$id)";
     mysqli_query($conn,$query);

?>
```

Comment: Use prepare statements. Never put variables directly to query.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `WHERE` clause from a logical point of view AFAIK.  As @sergio has mentioned, you should get into the good habit of using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: You can try to concatenate the table name in your query `"DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE m_id = ? OR id = ?"`. Use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) BTW.

Comment: can anyone please write whole correct query for me assuming i am extraordinary dumb.